# Regex; match the whole but only take part of it. How?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

In a multi-parted HTTP payload, parts are separated by an (presumably) arbitrary string. This field is called `boundary` and comes inside `Content-Type` header. An example would be

`Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=SOME_RANDOM_STRING`

One can pick up this line by matching `boundary=[a-zA-z0-9]+` (this regex is for demonstration purposes) and then taking the right hand side. I'm looking for a one-step functionality which;

for `boundary=efefef` returns `efefef`

using standard Python regex library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for this:

```
(?<=boundary=)[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Note that `A-z` (I guess that was a typo in your question) doesn't do quite what you want since there are some non-letter characters in the ASCII table between `Z` and `a`.

Comment: Yep, this is 'the' answer. Silly me, I've been doing something related to this while writing nginx configurations but it didn't even crossed my mind somehow.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that using captured groups: `()`:

```
import re

s = "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=SOME_RANDOM_STRING"

>>> print re.search(r'boundary=(\w+)', s).group(1)
SOME_RANDOM_STRING
```

#### Extension

You can also find all the matching strings using `findall`:

```
import re

s = """Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=SOME_RANDOM_STRING
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=SOME_RANDOM_STRING2
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=SOME_RANDOM_STRING3"""

result = re.findall(r'boundary=([\w]+)', s)

for i in result:
    print i

[OUTPUT]
SOME_RANDOM_STRING
SOME_RANDOM_STRING2
SOME_RANDOM_STRING3
```

Answer (score 3):

Although it's in the `email` module, you may wish to consider taking the HTTP payload and running it through `email.message_from_string` then that'll automatically parse content headers and payloads for you that you can then access.

Even for your simple string example it works, eg:

```
>>> import email
>>> s = "Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=SOME_RANDOM_STRING"
>>> mp = email.message_from_string(s)
>>> mp.get_boundary()
'SOME_RANDOM_STRING'
```

Comment: The step after this one requires email module so its not a problem. The original issue was having `boundary` value in the HTTP headers, not in a MIME-header. In other words, the payload (Which I define as the stuff after HTTP headers) was starting immediately with the boundary separator, instead of having a `Content-Type` header of its own, so when you try to execute `message_from_string` nothing got separated at all. I guess I will just put a MIME-header with having `Content-Type` field from HTTP headers and proceed.

Comment: @cemkyg sounds reasonable - was taking a stab you were introducing more work for yourself than you needed, but I understand now - sounds a pragmatic approach to take... Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use `split` function?

```
print s.split('boundary=')[1]
```

Comment: That will also capture anything after the `boundary` attribute, if present.